# Comparing keywords from one file to another file containing different tweet

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, loops

I am currently doing a project for my Python course which is sentiment analysis for tweets. We have only just finished reading/writing files and stuff like split() and strip() using Python is class, so I am still a noob at programming.

The project involves two files, the keywords.txt file and tweets.txt file, sample of the files are:

sample of tweets.txt:

> [41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life ... ARREIC
>
> [33.702900329999999, -117.95095704000001] 6 2011-08-28 19:03:13 Today
> is going to be the greatest day of my life. Hired to take pictures at
> my best friend's gparents 50th anniversary. 60 old people. Woo.

where the numbers in the brackets are coordinates, the numbers after that can be ignored, then the message/tweets comes after.

sample of keywords.txt:

> alone,1
>
> amazed,10
>
> excited,10
>
> love,10

where numbers represent the "sentimental value" of that keyword

What I am supposed to do is to read both files in Python, separate the words in each message/tweet and then check if any of the keywords is in each of the tweets, if the keywords are in the tweet, the add together the sentimental values. Finally, print the total of the sentiment values of each tweet, ignoring the tweets that does not contain any keywords.

So for example, the first tweet in the sample, two keywords are in the tweet (excited and love), so the total sentimental values would be 20.
however, in my code, it prints out the sentimental values separately as 10, 10, rather than printing out the total. And I also have no idea how to make it so that the function for checking keywords iterate over every tweet.

My code so far:

```
tweets = open("tweets.txt","r")
keywords = open("keywords.txt","r")

def tweetDataExtract (infile):
    line = infile.readline()
    if line == "":
        return []
    else:
        parts = line.split(" ",5)
        return parts

def keywordsDataExtract (infile):
    line = infile.readline()
    if line == "":
        return[]
    else:
        parts = line.split(",",1)
        return parts

tweetData = tweetDataExtract(tweets)
while len (tweetData) == 6:

    lat = float(tweetData[0].strip("[,"))
    long = float(tweetData[1].rstrip("]"))
    message = tweetData[5].split(" ")
    messageWords=[]
    #gets rid of all the punctuation in the strip() brackets
    for element in message:
        element = element.strip("!@.,?[]{}#-_-:)('=/%;&*+|<>`~\n")
        messageWords.append(element.lower())
    tweetData = tweetDataExtract(tweets)
    print(lat, long, messageWords)

    keywordsData = keywordsDataExtract(keywords)
    while len (keywordsData) == 2:

        words = keywordsData[0]
        happiness = int(keywordsData[1])
        keywordsData = keywordsDataExtract(keywords)

        count = 0
        sentiment = 0
        if words in messageWords:
            sentiment+=happiness
            count+=1
            print (lat, long, count, sentiment)




tweets.close()
keywords.close()
```

How can I fix the code?

PS I didn't know which part of the code would be essential to post, so I just posted the whole thing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you had initialised the variables `count` and `sentiment` inside the `while` loop itself. I hope you realise its consequences!!

Corrected code :

```
tweets = open("tweets.txt","r")
keywords = open("keywords.txt","r")

def tweetDataExtract (infile):
    line = infile.readline()
    if line == "\n":
        # print("hello")
        return tweetDataExtract(infile)

    else:
        parts = line.split(" ",5)
        return parts

keywordsData = [line.split(',') for line in keywords]

tweetData = tweetDataExtract(tweets)
while len(tweetData) == 6:
    lat = float(tweetData[0].strip("[,"))
    long = float(tweetData[1].rstrip("]"))
    message = tweetData[5].split(" ")
    messageWords=[]
    #gets rid of all the punctuation in the strip() brackets
    for element in message:
        element = element.strip("!@.,?[]{}#-_-:)('=/%;&*+|<>`~\n")
        messageWords.append(element.lower())
    tweetData = tweetDataExtract(tweets)
    count = 0
    sentiment = 0
    for i in range(0,len (keywordsData)):
        words = keywordsData[i][0]
        happiness = int(keywordsData[i][1].strip())
        if words in messageWords:
            sentiment+=happiness
            count+=1
    print (lat, long, count, sentiment)

tweets.close()
keywords.close()
```

See this new code (shorter and pythonic):

```
import string

dic = {}
tweets = []
with open("tweets.txt",'r') as f:
    tweets = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip() != ''] 

with open("keywords.txt",'r') as f:
    dic = {line.strip().split(',')[0]:line.strip().split(',')[1] for line in f if line.strip()!=''}

for t in tweets:
    t = t.split(" ",5)
    lat = float(t[0].strip("[,"))
    lon = float(t[1].rstrip("]"))
    sentiment = 0
    for word in t[5].translate(str.maketrans("","", string.punctuation)).lower().split():
        if word in dic:
            sentiment+=int(dic[word])
    print(lat,lon,sentiment)
```

Output:

```
41.29866963 -81.91532933 20
33.70290033 -117.95095704 0
```

Comment: @Pengibaby Try now.

Comment: Omg! it works! Thank you so much for taking the time to help!  :)   So what was wrong with it? Was it my second while loop that was causing the problem?

Comment: @Pengibaby The thing is, you are reading the tweets one by one. Thats fine. But for the `keywords`, you need it again and again, right?! So I stored it in a separate list and used it again and again. Presently, after the first tweet, keywords will always be Null as reading has finished. Is it fine now?

Comment: Oh okay, That makes sense! Thank you for the help and for explaining to me what I did wrong!  :)

Comment: @Pengibaby Glad, I could help.